# Google Cloud SQL and Wordpress "too many connections"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache2, google-cloud-sql

I´m having Problems with my Wordpress Setup and Google Cloud SQL.

I don´t have any Users than me on my Website yet, but even when i visit my site with a couple of tabs the CPU load and Memory Increases fast to the Maximum.
Also i sometimes get a MySQL Message from WP that there are too many connections.

I guess 250 is Max. and i often hit it.

I cannot see any D.O.S. attacks so it has to do with my own Config i guess.

I´m Using:

- Wordpress on Google Compute Engine
- Cloudflare with Flexible SSL
- W3 Total Cache
- WPML (database cash with memcache, Object Cache, etc.)

Does someone have any ideas what could cause that failure?

I also have Problems with pageload time. Could redirection Problems causing this Problem?

How to debug a Google Cloud-SQL as i don´t have no access to the Engine it self?

Comment: There is quite nice plugin to benchmark queries https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ which might help to track down issue

Comment: What instance size are your running in CloudSQL ? The hard limit is 100 pending connections regardless of tier, although this does not explain it since you mentioned there are no other users. Does the CloudSQL dashboard show you anything abnormal for Active connections ? you can check for previous days as well. Also, where are you seeing spikes in CPU and RAM ? it should be your GCE instance, right ? As a first suggestion, I would highly recommend you to use MySQL locally on GCE and then measure performance against CloudSQL. You will see a difference.

Comment: Really? I thought to seperte the database from the engine would bring me more performance?! - Yes, the Peaks are on the GCE of course.